# ¿Cómo encontrar la primera aparicón del valor de una llave dada como parametro en un diccionario?

Tags: python

Hola a toda la comunidad. Hoy traigo un problema similar a uno ya resuelto en esta plataforma. La diferencia es que para resolverlo debo valerme solo de ciclos for-in, while y de las funciones .values y .keys.

```
    def nota_dada_de_alguien(diccionario_curso:dict, nota_buscar:float)->str:
        encontrado=False
        longitud=len(diccionario_curso)
        for cada_valor in diccionario_curso.values():
            if nota_buscar!=cada_valor:
                nombre=None
        while encontrado==False and longitud>0:
            for cada_nombre in diccionario_curso.keys():
                if diccionario_curso[cada_nombre]==nota_buscar:
                    nombre=cada_nombre
                    encontrado=True
            longitud=longitud-1
    return nombre
```

La razón del retorno None al inicio del código es que si la nota que se pasa por parámetro no esta en el diccionario no debe regresar nada.
El problema que tengo es que el código debería retornarme el nombre de la persona en la cual se encontró por primera vez la nota
ej:

```
   [in] nota_dada_de_alguien({"Amelia":3.0,"Carlos":3.0},3.0)
   [out] 'Amelia'
```

En lugar de lo anterior mi código regresa lo siguiente:

```
    [in] nota_dada_de_alguien({"Amelia":3.0,"Carlos":3.0},3.0)
    [out] 'Carlos'
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me regrese la llave que guarda la primera aparición y no la ultima?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que por cada iteración del `while` el `for` anidado itera completamente. Es decir, cuando encuentra el nombre asignas `True` a `encontrado`, pero esto no rompe el `for`, seguirá iterando por lo que al final nombre será la última clave encontrada. Cuando el `for` termina el `while` si se romperá.  Puedes comprobarlo rompiendo el `for` con `break`:

```
def nota_dada_de_alguien(diccionario_curso:dict, nota_buscar:float)->str:
    encontrado=False
    longitud=len(diccionario_curso)
    for cada_valor in diccionario_curso.values():
        if nota_buscar!=cada_valor:
            nombre=None
    while not encontrado and longitud>0:
        for cada_nombre in diccionario_curso.keys():
            if diccionario_curso[cada_nombre]==nota_buscar:
                nombre=cada_nombre
                encontrado=True
                break
        longitud=longitud-1
    return nombre
```

Usas dos ciclos de más, el primer `for` sobra porque en el segundo `for` vuelves a comprobar el valor de la clave, el `while` solo itera una vez siempre, por lo que no tiene sentido alguno tampoco.

```
def nota_dada_de_alguien(diccionario_curso:dict, nota_buscar:float)->str:
    for nombre in diccionario_curso.keys():
        if diccionario_curso[nombre] == nota_buscar:
            break
    else:
        nombre = None
    return nombre
```

> **Nota**: esto solo funcionará y tiene sentido en Python >= 3.7. En versiones anteriores de Python los diccionarios no mantenían el orden de inserción de los items, por lo que sus vistas tenían un orden indeterminado. En Python 3.6 los diccionarios ya mantenían el orden de inserción, pero se consideraba aún un detalle de implementación, en Python >= 3.7 se considera una característica del lenguaje, por lo que se debe asumir que los diccionarios y sus vistas mantienen el orden de inserción en todo momento.

Comment: Si había pensado en el break, el problema es que no tengo permitido usar break y más de un return, de algún modo debo lograr que el ciclo termine sin estas dos herramientas :(

Answer (score 0):

Como lo menciono FJSevilla, solo funcionaria para un diccionario **OrderedDict** o usando Python 3.7 o superior

```py
def nota_dada_de_alguien(diccionario_curso:dict, nota_buscar:float) -> str:
    nombre = None
    for n in diccionario_curso:
        if nombre is None and diccionario_curso[n] == nota_buscar:
            nombre = n
    return nombre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya entendí como era el procedimiento :)